# Google API(LV24+) Of Arfcn isn't available on GalaxyS7

Tags: android

I am using the GalaxyS7(OS7.1.1), we can get the afrcn from GalaxyS6 and Galaxy note 4. but can not acquire the arfcn value by the google api.(It is always 0).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityLte.html#getEarfcn()

sumsang may blocked the api only on GalaxyS7....

Does anyone run into the same problem? 
Do you have any advice on how to do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with Samsung devices, none appear to be properly reporting data via `getEarfcn()` as of right now. It has been reported in [public forums](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=309343) and by e-mail, but the company has not responded.